# Displaying custom event data in Experience Profile

Tags: experience-profile, goals

I have some code to trigger goals (events) and add additional data to them, based upon [this documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/tracking-and-session/tracker/tracking-events/trigger-custom-event/index.html#capturing-custom-goal-and-event-data). The additional data is in the `Data` attribute and we also set the `DataKey` but no `CustomValues`. This works perfectly - we can see the data in the database (xdb shards).

In the experience profile, we can also find the triggered goals. But we can't see the extra data of the goal anywhere. In fact, we can't even find a spot where the data should be shown..

The goal is triggered when a whitepaper is downloaded. The custom data will identify the whitepaper (I don't want to create a goal for each whitepaper).

So, my question is: can this data, which is actually not that custom as I am still using the default `Data` property and not the `CustomValues`, be visualized in the Experience Profile? (and how)

Comment: Hello @Gatogordo, I am not able to find the triggered goal in experience profile. Do you have any idea? I have post question here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18934/how-can-i-find-out-triggered-goal-on-sitecore-item

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Goal data is not automatically show in experience profile. So you would need to do some SPEAK UI editing.

You can add more columns to the Goal View tab in the Experience Profile by adding new items under /sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Contact/PageSettings/Tabs/Activity/Activity Subtabs/Goals/GoalsPanel/Goal. So you'd add a new item that defines the Data Column.

Here's a pretty good article on the topic:
https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2016/05/31/display-context-of-sitecore-goal-in-experience-profile/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Managed to convert this to a Sitecore 9 solution. More details here: https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2018/02/displaying-extra-data-on-sitecore-9-goal.html

Answer (score 2):

In addition to my blog post Jarmo recommended, I released the code as a Marketplace module you can install into Sitecore to display the `Custom Data` of the `Goal`

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/D/Display_Goal_Context.aspx?sc_lang=en

It works for 8.1 and 8.2 however I am yet to test it on 9. The source code is also available here should you need to modify it in anyway

https://github.com/islaytitans/SitecoreGoalDescription

Comment: I checked your blog post and created a 9 version. See https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2018/02/displaying-extra-data-on-sitecore-9-goal.html Thanks for the original (very good) post!