# Trigger Goal on Sitecore Item does not appear in Experience Analytics

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I am working with Sitecore 9 update 1. I have created a goal, deployed it, and published it. After that, I have applied the goal on the home page and other Sitecore pages, the document I followed is here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-and-deploy-a-goal.html

I browsed these pages many times and closed the browser sessions to be written in xDB but I could not find any goals returned in Experience Analytics.

[image]

Also nothing related to my Goal exists in the `[Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[Interactions]` table in the database.

I do not know where the problem is. Is there any configuration that should be done first, or do the goals take time to be written in xDB?

Comment: Did you check this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18934/how-can-i-find-out-triggered-goal-on-sitecore-item ?

Comment: Just wanna check - Did you just publish the goals alone..? or you have also published Home page and other pages where you associated the goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have published the goals and also published Home page and other pages where you associated the goals.

You need to make sure that you have enabled indexing of anonymous contacts in the appropriate config file as given [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/enable-indexing-of-anonymous-contacts-in-the-xdb-index.html) and then set the default session timeout to 1 min as given [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/25819/4515). After doing these things, make the visit to a page (that has goal associated to it) in incognito mode, close the browser window. After 1 min, you should definitely see that data in Experience Analytics and also in Experience Profile (a new row will be added with last interaction column value as 1 min). Clicking on the Anonymous user should show the goals that were triggered in the visit

Comment: I published the pages where I associated the goals already, and the indexing of anonymous contacts is enabled already, but when I tried with logged in user the goals comes, so what do you think about the anonymous contacts that not come even if  the indexing of anonymous contacts is already enabled. should I rebuild the xDB search index again ?

Answer (score 0):

The session needs to end either expicitly by closing the browser or via code.

As per the documentation "**xDB data is not committed until after the user's session ends**"